# Celery cannot read value from env file after being run by supervisor

Tags: django, environment-variables, celery, supervisord

I am facing the issue, where If I run celery worker locally with `celery -A project worker -l info`. Celery tasks can access variables from .env file (I am using django-environ for reading .env file). But, in production server it's causing issues after being ran by supervisor. If a key doesn't exist in .env file it throws an error as it should be inside tasks. But, when I am properly setting all the variables it reads them without an error, but reads them as empty strings. I am also using firebase_admin for notifications. The same issue happens for it as well.

```
import firebase_admin

firebase_admin.initialize_app()
```

This is how I am setting the default app in settings.py and the fcm service account file is also in my project directory. Locally, the notification task sends the notification properly. But, after being ran by supervisor, it throws File Not Found error. This is quite confusing for me.

Below is my celery.conf file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project')


# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    pass


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

.env file:

```
ENV_TYPE="STAGING"
SECTET_KEY="SUPER_SECRET_KEY"
```

settings.py .env file reading part:

```
import environ

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env((BASE_DIR / '.env').as_posix())  # reading .env file
```

Comment: can you share the entire `supervisor` command and also the path where you storing `.env` file ?

Comment: .env is stored in project directory

Comment: worker.conf command section --->
command=/home/aaman007/project_dir/venv/bin/celery -A project worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1

Comment: since you got `File Not Found error`, just print the path right before where the error occurs and see if that path actually exists. That's the only way to debug.

Comment: I am storing the path in a variable in the .env file. Even though the entire path is there, it reads it as an empty string

Comment: In the first place, it's not able to read `.env` file, then how will it be able to read the path. Can you share the traceback of the error?

Comment: I just found the issue. In my supervisor file I used FILE_PATH as an environment variable and It had empty value previously and some other variables also had the same issue i,e previously empty. I also added the same variables on .env file. I was restarting the programs. But, as I changed conf file It didn't went through my head that after changing the conf file I need to run the reread and update command. Its working now. Thanks for the response.